# I want to create a dynamic next img function in Javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, dom, dom-events

I am trying to display image in HTML. With 2 functions where users can click next or previous image. The next button works until it reach the max array in `filePath` and create an error. this is what the console provided  `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. And the previous button doesn't work at all. I have tried looking into the solution in which mostly they use jQuery(I still haven't learned about it and do not understand at all). Is there any other way to limit the next image button so that it doesn't increment or decrement pass through the `filePath` array?

Here is my code :

```js
let filePath = ["img/frame/1.png", "img/frame/2.png", "img/frame/3.png", "img/frame/4.png", "img/frame/5.png", "img/frame/6.png", "img/frame/7.png", "img/frame/8.png", "img/frame/9.png"]

let imgResultEl = document.getElementById("img-result-el")
let prevBtnEl = document.getElementById("prev-btn-el")
let nextBtnEl = document.getElementById("next-btn-el")
let index = 0

let prevImg = () => {
  if (index >= filePath.length && index <= 0) {
    index--
    let newPath = filePath[index]
    imgResultEl.src = newPath
  }
}

let nextImg = () => {
  if (index <= filePath.length && index >= 0) {
    index++
    let newPath = filePath[index]
    imgResultEl.src = newPath
  }
}
prevBtnEl.addEventListener("click", prevImg)
nextBtnEl.addEventListener("click", nextImg)
```

Comment: JavaScript array indicies go from 0 to arraylength-1 so that is likely why you have issues. If not, please create a [mcve] using images from for example lorempixel

Comment: Do the `index--`/`index++` first when you enter these functions, and then use an `if` to check if the value got out of bounds afterwards. You might simply want to "wrap it around" then, meaning if the index was < 0, you set it to `filePath.length-1`, and if it got too big, then you reset it to 0.

Comment: how can `index >= filePath.length && index <= 0` ever be true? index can't be greater than 9 AND less than 0 at teh same time!! you mention not using jquery, not sure using jquery would help

Answer (score 0):

See the comments for the obvious mistakes in your script

Here is a much simpler solution that is just using the length and direction

jQuery is not the answer here

```js
let index = 0;
const navigateImg = (direction) => {
    index += direction;
    // Clamp index
    if (index < 0) index = 0;
    else if (index >= filePath.length) index = filePath.length - 1; // unless you want to wrap
    // Set the image source
    imgResultEl.src = filePath[index];
    // Update the button status
    prevBtnEl.disabled = index === 0;
    nextBtnEl.disabled = index >= filePath.length - 1;
};

// Initial button status
navigateImg(0);
prevBtnEl.addEventListener("click", () => navigateImg(-1));
nextBtnEl.addEventListener("click", () => navigateImg(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with this

```
let index = 0

let newSource = ()=>{
    if(filePath[index]==undefined){
        index = 0
    }
    let newPath = filePath[index]
    imgResultEl.src=newPath
}

let prevImg = () =>{
    index--
    newSource()
}

let nextImg = () =>{
    index++
    newSource()
}
prevBtnEl.addEventListener("click",prevImg)
nextBtnEl.addEventListener("click",nextImg)
```

Comment: This will load image 0 each time the file is not found. So users will not know why this happens. Also less DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) than mine :)

Comment: Yes, I understand. That's exactly what I want. As I only provide fixed amount of file, so this will suffice.